# Match function in excel macro giving only first result

Tags: excel, vba

i'm new to excal macros/vba, and i am encountering a problem which i do not know how to approach.

I have a workbook that includes several sheets. There is 1 file which is more or less a master list, and 3 files which are sort of a packing list.

I have put in a command button with a macro in the 3 packing list respectively that tells me if a certain item in the packing list exist in the master, and if it does it tells me which row it appears in. This is working fine, however my problem is that if a particular items appears several times in the master list(due to different purchase date), the macro only gives the first result.

I would like to know if there are any ways such that all possible results appears instead of just the first.

below is a sample of the code i used

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim k As Integer

For k = 3 To 1000

Cells(k, 24).Value = Application.Match(Cells(k, 2), Sheets("master").Range("B2:B1000"), 0)

Next k

End Sub
```

Comment: `Match` can only return one result. If you look for more than one result take a look into the `AutoFilter` function and the `Find` function. You will find many tutorials for that. • 2 Notes on your code: ① I recommend to use `Long` instead of `Integer` Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle. ② Make sure you specify a worksheet for **every** `Cells` or `Rang` object like you did for your last range in the code.

Comment: hello, thanks for your comment, i will read up on those and try to see if i can incorporate it into what i need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your "master" sheet data is a list of contiguous **not empty** cells from B2 down to last not empty one, then here's a different approach playing around a bit with

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim cell As Range

    With Worksheets("master") ' reference your "master" sheet
        With .Range("B2", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)) ' reference referenced sheet column B range from row 2 down to last not empty one
            For Each cell In Range("B3", Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)) ' loop through packinglist sheet (i.e. where button resides) column B cells from row 3 down to last not empty one
                If Not .Find(what:=cell.Value2, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then ' if current packinglist item is in "master"
                    .Replace what:=cell.Value2, replacement:=vbNullString, lookat:=xlWhole ' temporarily replace master item with a blank
                    cell.Offset(, 22).Value2 = Replace(.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Address(False, False), "B", "") ' write master list blanks rows in packinglist sheet current item row and column "X"
                    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = cell.Value2 ' restore master list current packinglist item value
                End If
            Next
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: hello!
yes, my rows in that particular column are all filled without any blank cells inbetween. I have tried your code and the function was what i was looking for. I try to understand the logic and purpose of each function from there so edit my other workbooks/worksheets and also try to given an output based on a different column(S/N) instead of the row number itself.
Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [dictionary](http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Dictionary_en.html) to store every item in the master sheet, and everytime you find it duplicate, add another number with its row like this:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim MasterKeys As Object

    MasterKeys = FillDictionary(MasterKeys)

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MySheet") 'change MySheet for your actual sheet name

        Dim arr As Variant
        arr = .UsedRange.Value 'drop your data inside an array

        Dim i As Long

        For i = 3 To UBound(arr) 'loop through all the rows in your data
            If MasterKeys.Exists(arr(i, 2)) Then arr(i, 24) = MasterKeys(arr(i, 2))
        Next i

        .UsedRange.Value = arr 'drop back your data

    End With

End Sub
Function FillDictionary(MasterKeys As Object) As Object

    Set MasterKeys = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With Workbooks("MasterWorkbook.xlsx").Sheets("master") 'change MasterWorkbook for the actual filename of your master workbook

        Dim LastRow As Long
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row 'find the last row on column B

        Dim C As Range
        For Each C In .Range("B2:B" & LastRow) 'loop through the range
            If Not MasterKeys.Exists(C.Value) Then
                MasterKeys.Add C.Value, C.Row
            Else
                MasterKeys(C.Value) = MasterKeys(C.Value) & "," & C.Row
            End If
        Next C

    End With

End Function
```